# How to setup PHP Error message function help URL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have met an error showing 
`Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: User xx already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home/xxxx on line 22`

In the error message, the word `function.mysql-pconnect` was showing a link relatively to my page, i.e. `<a href="mysql_pconnect">mysql_pconnect</a>`

How can I setup the link for it to `http://www.php.net/mysql_pconnect` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `php.ini` setting `docref_root`, as described in [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.docref-root). Basically you need to set the URL to the manual in there. If you want it to link to the official php.net manual, you can set it to `docref_root=http://www.php.net/`

Also don't forget to set the `docref_ext` value to ""